# Unable to access front- and backend after changing to HTTPS

Tags: php, admin, security, user

I looked for a way to change from HTTP to HTTPS.

By mistake I switched my insecure and secure URL in config-web-secure/, and added the word magento to them both. As a result I get a 403 error on my admin panel and website. I tried changing the URL in the PHP but that didn't work.

Comment: did you find your solution ??

Answer (score 2):

I think you can set your sites secure and unsecure URLs from your database.

For that in your database make some changes in `core_config_data` table.

In table search `"web/"` from "search" tab in the header (using phpMyAdmin or similar). Edit `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` and
paste the URL of your site.

After that set value `0` to `web/secure/use_in_frontend` and `web/secure/use_in_adminhtml`.

I have attached a screenshot for better understanding

[image: screenshot]

(click to enlarge)

Answer (score 0):

You can do database changes on core_config_data table using magerun command line tool for [Magento 1](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun)

and for [Magento 2](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2)

After you have installed magerun, you should go to webroot and write the following command to get config from core_config_data table

```
 n98magerun.phar config:get web/
```

you can set your unsecure url:

```
n98magerun.phar config:set web/unsercure/base_url http://yourwebsite.com
```

And secure url :

```
n98magerun.phar config:set web/sercure/base_url http://yourwebsite.com
```